# Lasso feature selection consistency: $\frac{\lambda_n}{n} \rightarrow 0, \frac{\lambda_n}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow \infty$ hold at the same time

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, lasso, consistency

In some references regarding sign consistency of Lasso such as

*Zhao, Peng; Yu, Bin*, [**On model selection consistency of Lasso**](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/v7/zhao06a.html), J. Mach. Learn. Res. 7, 2541-2563 (2006). [ZBL1222.62008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1222.62008).

there is a condition such that

$\frac{\lambda_n}{n} \rightarrow 0, \frac{\lambda_n}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow \infty$

(In the above paper $\sqrt{n}$ is indeed $n^\frac{1+c}{2}$ for $0 \leq c < 1$). I understand $\frac{\lambda_n}{n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n$ goes infinity, but how does $\frac{\lambda_n}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow \infty$ hold at the same time? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Suppose $\lambda_n = n^\frac{3}{4}$ , then the two conditions hold. The choice of 3/4 is arbitrary, perhaps from this example @hp257 can see how this can occur in general.

Comment: Thanks a lot @aginensky! That's very clear. I was thinking $\lambda_n$ is a constant and $n$ is a variable... Thanks again for your kind help!